# Uploading multiple files on the server Using JSP

Tags: java, javascript, facebook, jsp, user-interface

I have often wonder how Facebook is able to handle uploading multiple files on the server when I am uploading my pictures.

I am quite not sure how it is being implemented.  As I know, you could only send one file to the server through http one at a time unless you are going to make use of Applets.

Does anybody know how Facebook implements this? Is this Flash or an applet or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special that you need to do on your web page - multiple `<input type="file">` elements in the same `<form>` will upload multiple files at once.

The tricky part is handling all those files on the server. Take a look at a library such as [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)

**Edit**

You might want to take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582126/best-way-to-upload-multiple-files-from-a-browser) - people have suggested quite a few readily available components that you can use (note that these are for the client-side i.e. in the browser. You still need to handle the uploaded files on the server using something like the FileUpload library I mentioned before)

Comment: Hi Sir,  I already have Apache Commons File Upload setup at the server and that I have done using multiple input of file type.  Facebook allows you to browse your directory and then select all pictures at once.  This is the functionality that I am looking for.  By the way your link is very interesting.

Comment: Aah, I see - you want a single file select element but multiple files. As far as I know, you can't do that with just HTML/JS, you need something like Java, Flash or similar, something that will let you access the client filesystem and use a custom file select dialog. I checked and Facebook has a Flash uploader, if I remember correctly, it was a Java applet before. And if you see their 'simple uploader', it's a form with multiple file input elements. So I guess the thread I linked to is probably a good place to start for a plugin that will help you do this.